# Mutations Commands Not Working But Queries Work Perfect

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, aws-appsync

GraphQL queries work fine, returning expected results. But mutation commands not working, returning an object of values null like,

```
{"data":{"create_event":{"event_id":null,"name":null,"__typename":"Event"}}}
```

My versions for aws-appsync,aws-appsync-react are respectively 1.0.22, 1.0.13

react ^16.8.6
react-apollo "^2.5.6"

```
const addEventMutation = gql`mutation addEvent($name: String!){
      create_event(input:{name: $name}){
        event_id
        name
      }
    }`;

    client.mutate({
      mutation: addEventMutation,
      variables: {
        name: "Test"
      }
    }).then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
```

This is the results I am getting:

```
{"data":{"create_event":{"event_id":null,"name":null,"__typename":"Event"}}}
```

Comment: If used without input key, It returns like below     {"data":null,"errors":[{"path":null,"locations":[{"line":2,"column":16,"sourceName":null}],"message":"Validation error of type UnknownArgument: Unknoawn field argument name @ 'create_event'"}]}

Comment: Can you share your mutation and it's mapping templates?